# Where statement not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have read and read posts that seem to answer my exact question, but nothing I try works.  I'm clearly missing something simple.  I have a report showing employee overtime.  I want the user to be able to click a hyperlink or button for the overtime entry and open a form to edit the entry.

The following code pulls up a parameter input box for Overtime_ID.  Also entering the Overtime_ID manually will open the correct form, but it seems to default to the first record in the underlying table.

```
Private Sub Overtime_ID_Click()

Dim recordID As Integer
recordID = Me.Overtime_ID
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditOvertime",,, "Overtime_ID = " & recordID, acFormEdit

End Sub
```

Record Source for frmEnterOvertime is a table - Overtime Awards. 
The columns in that table are: 
Overtime ID (AutoNumber and PK)
Entry Date
Overtime Date
Squad List (short text)
Overtime Hours(number)
Supervisor(number)
Comment(short text)
Mandatory (Yes/No)
Correction (Yes/No)
Officer ID(Number)

Comment: I have tested recordID by assigning it to a MsgBox and it returns the appropriate numeric value.

Comment: Please post the table (cols) or query (SQL) for which the form is bound. The pop-up param box means *Overtime_ID* cannot be found in the form's recordsource.

Comment: Record Source for frmEnterOvertime is a table Overtime Awards.  The columns in that table are: Overtime ID (AutoNumber and PK), Entry Date, Overtime Date, Squad List (short text), Overtime Hours(number), Supervisor(number), Comment(short text), Mandatory (Yes/No), Correction (Yes/No), Officer ID(Number)

Comment: As mentioned, please post the columns and data type.

Comment: Will the above comment work, or is there a better way to copy/paste table columns from access?

Comment: You should edit your post with that information and not in comments. See link below tags. And is there really a space in *Overtime ID*? If so, that is your problem. You cannot simply swap space for underscore.

Comment: Yes there is a space.  I am learning as I go, and I read later that spaces in column names are bad, but I have so much work into this I don't know how to go back and change it without redoing all queries and references to that name.  Is there an easy way to reference it with the space?

Comment: Just changed Overtime_ID to [Overtime ID] and it works like a charm!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Parfait, please post an answer so I can accept it.  You have already answered my question, but I want to make sure you get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *Overtime ID* has a space in its name, simply bracket `[]` or use backticks in `OpenForm` call. You cannot simply use underscore as replacement as that changes the column identifier.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditOvertime",,, "[Overtime ID] = " & recordID, acFormEdit

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditOvertime",,, "`Overtime ID` = " & recordID, acFormEdit
```

And do note the *where* argument can use any compliant SQL `WHERE` condition.